# Create managed wrapper in javascript to pass to silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I want to create a wrapper for managed object to pass as an argument to a Silverlight application.

this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645087%28v=VS.95%29.aspx gives following example:

```
var a = Content.services.createObject("jsonSerializer").serialize(jsObject);
```

But it fails with `Content undefined` exception. Where should `Content` property be coming from? Is there a .js file that I need to include?

Silverlight version: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution is:

```
var a = control.Content.services.createObject('SomeRegisteredManagedType');
```

where control is the  element:

```
var control = document.getElementById("mySilverlightComponent");
```

Assuming HTML:

```
    <object style='visibility:visible;' id='mySilverlightComponent' data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" 
    width="100" height="100">
      <param name="source" value="../../../../../Silverlight/SilverlightApplication2.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object>
```